# GWT: how do I include static nested classes in module.xml files?

Tags: java, gwt

I have an interface class from Project-A which contains a static class.

I want to import this class to my gwt Project-B, so I wrote a module.xml file to include the interface class in Project-A and tried to use it.

Here is how it looks like:

```
<module>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <source path="">
        <include name="IDefinition.java"/>
        <include name="metadata/input/IInputMetaDataProvider.java"/>
        <include name="util/IXMLTagHelper.java"/>
        <include name="util/XMLTagHelper.java"/>
    </source>
</module>
```

Other classes are imported without any problem, but the class inside IInputMetaDataProvider is not imported. Here is the error:

```
[ERROR] [onboardingtool] - com.xxx.xxx.xxx.metadata.input.IInputMetaDataProvider.EnumeratedDomainInfo cannot be resolved to a type
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Try adding it `<include name="metadata/input/IInputMetaDataProvider.EnumeratedDomainInfo .java"/>` too

Comment: @alkis, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was caused by other issues. The interface imported some other classes which I did not put into module.xml. Once I included them, it works like a charm.